# Trouble understanding pointer cast from struct address to (uint *)

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm having some trouble at work explaining the following C code to myself and nobody can seem to give me a clear answer, so this is literally my last resort.

```
struct s some_buffer;

uint *RxPtr;

RxPtr = (uint *)&some_buffer;
```

I understand that a type-cast is the only method of forcing `RxPtr` to point to `some_buffer` because `some_buffer` is of type `struct` and `RxPtr` can only point to `uint`. What's giving me so much trouble is the `*` in `(uint *)`. I don't understand why the author of this code would want `some_buffer` to be of type `uint *` instead of just `uint`.

I've only found 1 other person asking this type of question. The answer, applied to my question, would be that `&some_buffer` gives you a `(struct *)` which needs to be type-casted into `(uint *)`.

This makes sense when I think of it that way. But that's essentially saying     `&` = `struct *`. `&` is not a pointer, so how does `&some_buffer` give me a `(struct *)`? And like I said earlier, why would the author of this code want `some_buffer` to be of type `uint *` instead of just `uint`?

Comment: `&` is the "address-of" operator. Applying it produces a pointer to the operand. This is covered in the early chapters of your "introduction to C" book. `RxPtr` is a `uint*` because that's what the surrounding code needs.

Comment: XY Problem: The correct way to serialise a struct is to serialise its fields properly and portably. **Without** casting and warnings.

Comment: You would be surprised, moldbnilo. All intro C books state what a pointer is, and what & is, but none go into the detail that & produces a pointer to the operand, if that is correct. I've been through about 5 C books in the last couple days. Thanks for the answer though, it certainly cleared a few of my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If RxPtr would be an unsigned int, it wouldn't be a pointer.

The reason why someone lets a pointer to a value point to the address of a structure is usually to be able to fill the structure without caring about the structure elements.

Assuming struct some_buffer being something like:

```
struct some_buffer
{
 uint header;
 uint first_data;
 uint second_data;
};
```

and rx_data being an array of three uints.

Then you can fill the data of some_buffer with:

```
some_buffer.head = rx_data[0];
some_buffer.first_data = rx_data[1];
some_buffer.second_data = rx_data[2];
```

You could also point an uint pointer at the struct though and write:

```
ptr = (uint *) &some_buffer;
ptr[0] = rx_data[0];
ptr[1] = rx_data[1];
ptr[2] = rx_data[2];
```

And when you are that far you can even simplify it further and write:

```
ptr = (uint *) &some_buffer;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   ptr[i] = rx_data[i];
}
```

As each element in the structure is the sizeof(uint) and the pointer also increments by sizeof(uint) as it points to uint, you fill the three elements of the structure without actually needing to know the name of the structure elements. The pointer code will work even if you rename header to mynewheader.

If RxPtr would be an unsigned int, you couldn't do this. Incrementing an unsigned int would merely result in the unsigned int having a different value, but not pointing at different content of some_buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`some_buffer` is a thing. `&some_buffer` is the *address* of that thing.  Now, an address is a location in memory, and any type can be stored at an address.  In this case, &some_buffer is the address for a struct.

`RxPtr` has also been declared as an address, intended to store `uint`.  It may be that the original author knows the struct starts with a `uint` and just cast the pointer to reflect that.  But it is bad practice, and that may be what's misleading you.

Answer (score -1):

> I've only found 1 other person asking this type of question. The answer, applied to my question, would be that `&some_buffer` gives you a `(struct *)` which needs to be type-casted into `(uint *)`.

Some days I wonder if some of the difficulty of grasping pointers is due to C muddying the waters by using `type *` to denote addresses instead of `type &`. If it used `&` instead then `*` would much more naturally be the opposite of `&`.

```
// wishful thinking
int x;
int &addr = &x;
int y = *addr;
```

But that is not what C does. When you take the address of a variable with `&x` you get a `type *`. It seems perfectly natural to me now, twenty years after first learning pointers, but I remember when I was young that this syntax seemed awfully confusing.

In the world that we live in, C doesn't think of `&x` as the "address of `x`". Instead, it's a "pointer to `x`", and so the resulting type is `int *` not `int &`.

```
// reality
int x;
int *addr = &x;
int y = *addr;
```

Variables are usually said to hold *pointers*, moreso than *addresses*. Addresses is still correct, mind you. It's not wrong to say addresses. It's just that the two words are synonymous and "pointer" is more common.

```
(uint &) &some_buffer;   // wishful thinking
(uint *) &some_buffer;   // reality
```

This explains why, then, pointer casts are written as `(uint *)`. `&some_buffer` gives you a "pointer to `some_buffer`" and `(uint *)` casts that pointer to another type.

Comment: Thanks John. Based on what you and molbdnilo said, it's more clear that & produces a pointer. I had trouble believing this at first because I thought only pointers could point to things. But I guess an & isn't a pointer, it just implicitly produces one behind the scenes? Is this correct to say?
As for the confusion around pointers, the problem is that books don't go into enough detail. All 5 that I've been through say the same exact thing. & gives an address, * is the indirection operator, and they are inverses of each other. Details could confuse beginners, but lack of details confuses me!

Comment: `&` gives an address, `*` is the indirection operator, and they are inverses of each other. This is true, and is the sensible part. There are other uses of `*` besides as the indirection operator, and that's where it gets confusing. `*` is also used in type declarations and in typecasts to denote pointer (AKA address) types. This is *not* the indirection operator. The `*` in `int *` is not the same as the `*` in `*variable`. The former is a type name, the latter is the indirection operator.